# Suggestions for writing self feedback for a newly hired employee

Tags: work-environment, feedback, new-hires

I've started working in a software company about 3 weeks ago, and actually I have no projects assigned to me yet. Now I need to write **self feedback** by following company's policy.

The bellow are general guidelines:

> Please mention things that went well and things to improve; give examples if possible. Justify your choices for metrics. Also mention topics in addition to the metrics. Add personal thoughts and feelings. Suggest topics for the quarterly meeting to discuss: both positive feedback and opportunities for improvements.

So I'm little bit confused about what should I write in my self feedback when I spent 3 weeks on reading books, drinking coffee, playing play-station and staff like that.

Comment: Obviously the first thing that needs to improve is assigning projects to you.

Comment: I've considered that point (:

Comment: Please let me know if it is only my understanding, but creating a self feedback is to review your own self. Which would make sense if the company would like the new collague to assess his first short period at the company. It would mean a not best practice, but so it is not about giving feedback from the new employee to the company, but to self-check the new person on his own.

Comment: Right, but I don't understand how should I describe myself in the company where I did "nothing" during those 3 weeks

Comment: I recently got hired (also software engineering) and my company made me write the yearly self-evaluation too. Within 2~3 weeks of being hired. I noticed it was mass mailed to the whole company. I asked my manager what to write in it and he basically said to just write as much as I could. But he also said he understuud if I hardly write anything in it. as I havn't really "started" yet. Don't think too long or hard on it.

Comment: Have you asked your manager what you should do?

Comment: You've done nothing for 3 weeks and can't give yourself feedback? That explains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can't really have pertinent feedback for the company yet, but what you might already have done is observation. You could give them input of what you liked so far, what can be improved and the general feeling of the company (by observing).

Every person is unique in it's own way and giving feedback, even if not very conclusive, can be a factor in the next decisions that will be taken in the company.

If you haven't made too many observations, you can input your desires of how the perfect work environment looks like (you need to specifically mention this on your form - that this is not a feedback, but an input as to how the perfect workplace looks like in your eyes).

Comment: Well, I'm agree with your suggestions (:

Answer (score 1):

**Ask your manager**.

We certainly cannot give you better insight into what the company expects from your self-assessment.

Comment: Self assessments are pretty common, I think that we can help.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings, I agree the self-assessments are common and there are lots of questions related to them that we can help with, but this specific question is best suited to a conversation with OPs manager, not a Q&A site.

Comment: Perhaps, but that is not an acceptable answer here on its own.  It would be fine to explain that at the end of an answer that attempts to give some guidance, but Ask someone else is never an acceptable answer on SE.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I disagree. We have an entire close reason that basically says "go talk to your company/manager/HR/a lawyer". Many answers boil down to "just ask/talk to the person who can resolve this for you". I'll agree that I could have added additional fluff to provide better direction as to how to approach the manager, etc

Comment: @ChrisG - That is a close reason not an answer.

Comment: [Meta Question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4082/16) where this answer is being discussed.